# How can I get the request path in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-headers, request

I have a base controller that log errors and I want include in the log message *ALL* request data, ALL headers and request body. How can I do that in CodeIgniter?

Comment: if you are using php 5.4 you can call `headers_list()` function, which will get you the whole request headers. and by default codeigniter session saves the `ip_address , browser` any many other stuff. look for it [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: But what about the whole body?

Comment: So no CI native way then? Beside, the method is not the body or I don't get you ;)

Comment: try this: `file_get_contents('php://input')` , and sorry for the last comment I got it the idea in a wrong way. and about codeigniter native way. I don't think so.

Comment: or in codeigniter, you need to try [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: Thanks. `$this->input->post()` could substitute `file_get_contents('php://input')`? Beside $_SERVER, how can I get the original (before rewrite) URL path in a POST request?

Comment: first, no.. `$this->input->post()` gets you the in-body passed params. and for the second question. try `$this->uri->uri_string();` and send it with the post.

Comment: And what else beside the in body params return `file_get_contents('php://input')`? excellent the `$this->uri->uri_string();` thing, where do you read that? Thanks again, if you want create a reply with all this information and I will select your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Testing now, realize that `$this->uri->uri_string();` just include the path, not the query parameters. In *http://localhost/api/?var1=value1*, the *var1=value1* is excluded from the result of `$this->uri->uri_string();`, so I'm still without know how get `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in CI, lol

Comment: yes, it just include the path as you requested. for the query you need the `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: So for the whole URL not CodeIgniter way... just $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? Sorry ask again, just to confirm.

Comment: Ok, wait I'm writing you an answer in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter `$this->input`  which is equivalent to `file_get_contents('php://input')`    contains all the Body request (if any) an output from foo `var_dump($this->input)` would look like:

```
object(CI_Input)[9]
  public 'ip_address' => boolean false
  public 'user_agent' => boolean false
  public '_allow_get_array' => boolean true
  public '_standardize_newlines' => boolean true
  public '_enable_xss' => boolean false
  public '_enable_csrf' => boolean false
  protected 'headers' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'security' => &
    object(CI_Security)[8]
      protected '_xss_hash' => string '' (length=0)
      protected '_csrf_hash' => string '' (length=0)
      protected '_csrf_expire' => int 7200
      protected '_csrf_token_name' => string 'ci_csrf_token' (length=13)
      protected '_csrf_cookie_name' => string 'ci_csrf_token' (length=13)
      protected '_never_allowed_str' => 
        array (size=10)
          'document.cookie' => string '[removed]' (length=9)
          'document.write' => string '[removed]' (length=9)
          '.parentNode' => string '[removed]' (length=9)
          '.innerHTML' => string '[removed]' (length=9)
          'window.location' => string '[removed]' (length=9)
          '-moz-bindin.......//and many other data.
```

and for the headers laso you have the new command in PHP 5.4 which is `headers_list()`. and also, many other data can be contained in the **CI seesion** like: `ip_address, user_agent ,last_activity`

Comment: Just want add that for the complete URI, includind the possible qury parameters in a POST request, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the only option I have found so far, cos in the above `var_dump($this->input)` I can't found the complete URI of the request. Thanks all for yours replies.

Answer (score 0):

### For header details

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
$reqUserIp = $this->input->ip_address();
$userAgent = $this->agent->agent_string();
$reqHeaders = $this->input->request_headers();
```

Comment: Why `$this->agent->agent_string();`? With `$this->input->request_headers();` I not have all headers? What about the whole body? I'm looking for a complete request dump.

Comment: Yes, I know, but agent is part of HTTP headers, so why include it beside headers? or is that `$this->input->request_headers();` don't have all the headers. I must dump whatever kind of request that don't meet some characteristics, being POST or GET or whatever other HTTP method.

Comment: For example, in a POST request, the URI path is not in the header as far I seem. I just end using $_SERVER, but I just wondering if exist a more CodeIgnitering way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a post controller [hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html).

- Enable hooks in **application/config/config.php**.
- Then in **application/config/hooks.php**;

  ```
  $hook['post_controller'] = array(
                          'class'    => 'PostController',
                          'function' => 'log_it',
                          'filename' => 'PostController.php',
                          'filepath' => 'hooks',
                          'params'   => array()
                          );
  ```

  ---
- Create a file in **application/hooks/PostController.php**

  ```
  <?php

  class PostController {

  private $ci;
  private $filepath;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->ci =& get_instance();
      $log_path = ($this->ci->config->item('log_path') != '') ? $this->ci->config->item('log_path') : APPPATH.'logs/';
      $this->filepath = $log_path.'action_log';
  }

  public function log_it($log_message=NULL) {
      if ($log_message == NULL) {
          $log_message = date('d/m/Y H:i:s')."::";
          $log_message .= $this->ci->session->userdata('username')."::";
          $log_message .= $this->ci->input->ip_address()."::";
          $log_message .= $this->get_client_ip()."::";
          $log_message .= $this->ci->router->class."::";
          $log_message .= $this->ci->router->method."::";
          $log_message .= uri_string()."::";
          if (isset($_POST)) {
              foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                  $log_message .= "[$key] => $value;";
              }
          }
          $log_message .= "\r\n";
      }


      $fp = fopen($this->filepath, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE);
      fwrite($fp, $log_message);
      fclose($fp);
  }

  private function get_client_ip() {
      if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {   //check ip from share internet
          $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {   //to check ip is pass from proxy
          $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      } else {
          $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      }
      return $ip;
    }
   }

  ?>
  ```

Comment: This is a step by step, and I'm not pretty sure that have all the request data, I need dump to log all the request data.